# Возможные аналоги mod_deflate и mod_gzip

Tags: php, apache, perl, хостинг, deflate

Хостер отключил mod_deflate и mod_gzip по соображениям заработка на трафике.
Существуют ли какие-либо аналоги этих модулей? Может костыли, использующие PHP или Perl?

Чисто теоретически, если PHP будет выдавать результат функции gzcompress с заголовком Content-Encoding: gzip, это сработает?

Comment: надо ещё обрабатывать наличие информации от клиента: поддерживает ли он сжатие. а передаёт ли эту информацию ваш *http-сервер* вашему интерпретатору можете выяснить только вы. пример сжатия: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/13/10/0/compressing-output

Comment: Это будет в конце. А сейчас у меня другая проблема:
header('Content-Encoding:gzip');
header('Content-Type:'.mime_content_type($filename));
echo gzcompress($filename);

Клиент ругается на ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: я думаю, что это уже явно совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: в чем проблема сменить хостера? Предложений на рынке масса без идиотских соображений.

Comment: В том, что у меня нет денег на нормального хостера. Надеюсь, это объяснение подходит.
Открыл новый вопрос с проблемой выполнения.

Answer (score 1):

Странная постановка вопроса, если найдете аналоги апачевских модулей, я сомневаюсь, что хостер вам их подключит.

По поводу "костылей" на PHP отписал [в вашем дочернем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510071/206953)