# Эмуляция mod_deflate средствами PHP

Tags: php, gzip, deflate

По определенным причинам я не могу использовать ни mod_deflate, ни mod_gzip. Поэтому я пытаюсь реализовать его работу средствами PHP.
Есть следующий код:

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents($filename);
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filename));
echo gzcompress($filecontents);
```

Однако в итоге вылетает ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED в Хроме. В чем может быть проблема? Браузер, конечно же, поддерживает распаковку gzip.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php

Comment: Не работает, пробовал. Все, что связано с GZIP работает. А DEFLATE или ZLIB не работает

Comment: Уверены что остальной код без ошибки отработал и 

`$filecontents = file_get_contents($filename);
header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filename));
echo $filecontents;`

все правильно возвращает?

Comment: Да, я все проверял. В конце концов даже заменил на
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$filecontents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
C GZIP работает, с DEFLATE или ZLIB - нет

Answer (score 1):

Все на самом деле просто, нужна только одна строка

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>Это должно быть сжатой страницей.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Курите маны: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-gzhandler.php

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php

```
<?php

    $filecontents = file_get_contents($filename);
    header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filename));

    // mod_gzip
    // header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    // echo gzencode($filecontents); 

    // mod_deflate
    header('Content-Encoding: deflate');
    echo gzencode($filecontents, 9, FORCE_DEFLATE);
```

Comment: Это работает, но это mod_gzip, а не mod_deflate

Comment: Судя по всему вам Mark Adler ответил уже на ваш вопрос в английской версии. Что по спекам это и есть  HTTP "deflate"

Comment: То, что он ответил, не работает

Comment: Что значит не работает? Код в моем примере прекрассно открылся в браузере. Данные были сжаты для передачи. В чем проблема?

Comment: Код вашего примера - mod_gzip, а не mod_deflate. Mark Adler посоветовал gzcompress() в качестве deflate(который на самом деле zlib, а не deflate). Однако на gzcompress браузер ругается ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Comment: Из http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php `In PHP 5.4.0 and later, FORCE_DEFLATE generates RFC 1950 compliant output, consisting of a zlib header, the deflated data, and an **Adler** checksum.`  Потом открываем http://stackoverflow.com/users/1180620/mark-adler и https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Adler. Мне что-то подсказываэт что ему можно верить :)

Comment: Ну, не думаю, что это он, но не в том дело. Он посоветовал совсем другое.
Пользую PHP 7, вывод результата gzencode($filecontents, 9, FORCE_DEFLATE) все-равно вызывает ошибку

Comment: Тебе обяснили что FORCE_GZIP это и есть http deflate название не важно. По сути http deflate  = raw deflate + zlib обертка. Даже ссылку на спеки он дал. А вообше какая разница, если задача что бы сжимало и распокововало?

Comment: Перечитайте, пожалуйста, что он пишет. "So HTTP "deflate" == zlib.". Там о GZIP-е ни слова.
Разница есть. В скорости запаковки и распаковки из-за контрольных сумм и header-а

Comment: UPD: В голове перемкнуло. Content-Encoding: deflate. У меня был gzip. Мне казалось...

Comment: ;) happens to the best of us